# ListBox throwing ArgumentOutOfRangeException when adding to DataSource

Tags: c#, listbox, datasource, bindinglist

I'm trying use a `BindingList` as a `DataSource` for a `ListBox` in C# WinForms, but whenever I try to add items to the `BindingList`, I get an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` thrown.  The following code demonstrates the problem (assume a form with `ListBox listBox1`):

```
BindingList<string> dataSource = new BindingList<string>();
listBox1.DataSource = dataSource;
dataSource.Add("Test1"); // Exception, here.
```

Note that if `dataSource` already has items in it, I do not get the exception:

```
BindingList<string> dataSource = new BindingList<string>();
dataSource.Add("Test1");
listBox1.DataSource = dataSource;
dataSource.Add("Test2"); // Appears to work correctly.
```

I can work around the problem by setting the `DataSource` property to `null` before adding an item, and re-setting the `DataSource` afterward, but this feels like a hack, and I'd like to be able to avoid doing so.

Is there a (non-hack) way to use an empty `DataSource` on a `ListBox`, such that adding items to it doesn't throw exceptions?

**Edit**: Stack Trace:

> System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.ListBox.SelectedIndex.set(int
>   value) + 0x1ec bytes
>     System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.ListControl.DataManager_PositionChanged(object
>   sender, System.EventArgs e) + 0x2e
>   bytes
>     System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.CurrencyManager.OnPositionChanged(System.EventArgs
>   e) + 0x39 bytes
>     System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.CurrencyManager.ChangeRecordState(int
>   newPosition, bool validating, bool
>   endCurrentEdit, bool
>   firePositionChange, bool pullData) +
>   0x14f bytes
>     System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.CurrencyManager.List_ListChanged(object
>   sender,
>   System.ComponentModel.ListChangedEventArgs
>   e) + 0x2e4 bytes
>     System.dll!System.ComponentModel.BindingList.OnListChanged(System.ComponentModel.ListChangedEventArgs
>   e) + 0x17 bytes
>     System.dll!System.ComponentModel.BindingList.FireListChanged(System.ComponentModel.ListChangedType
>   type, int index) + 0x35 bytes
>     System.dll!System.ComponentModel.BindingList.InsertItem(int
>   index, System._*Canon item) + 0x3f
>   bytes
>
>     mscorlib.dll!System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection.Add(System.*_Canon
>   item) + 0x76 bytes

Comment: No repro, post the stack trace of the exception.

Comment: I'm feeling kinda stupid--it's an exception that .Net handles internally; my debugger was just set to trigger on all thrown exceptions.  Next time, I'll be sure to "Continue" until I get an actual crash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out I had everything checked in the "Exceptions" dialog (Debug->Exceptions).  So, the exception exists, but is (silently) handled by the .Net framework.  Continuing program execution displays the expected results.

Answer (score 0):

Do you possibly have an event handler attached to some event on your `ListBox` that could be causing this? I am not able to reproduce the behavior you're describing.

I created a completely blank WinForms project, with a single `ListBox` bound to a `BindingList<string>`, added the value "Test" to the list (after setting the `ListBox.DataSource` property), and the item "Test" appeared in the box, as expected.

I'd take a look at your `ListBox` as well as your `BindingList<string>` to see if either one has some attached event handlers you might be missing.

Comment: My problem exists in what appears to be the same configuration you describe, i.e. brand new WinForms project with a single ListBox; no extraneous event handlers.

Comment: @TreDubZedd: And this is a standard `System.Windows.Forms.ListBox`? At the moment I'm with Hans—can't reproduce what you're seeing. A stack trace would definitely be helpful.

Comment: It looks like it's an exception that .Net handles internally.  Oops.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and after several research, I found that the only workaround to avoid this .Net error was to assign only the BindingList to the DataSource when the list is not empty.

If it can change, you can make a dummy object that you always keep in the list, and you removed it when the list is not empty.

Finaly, its not worth it to find a way to avoid ArgumentOutOfRangeException to be thrown.